# Set <Header> above Other Elements - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some html and while things are loading I have a `<div>` that display while it loads, when it is loading currently the loading appears above everything, but I want the header to be above the loading screen. Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="loading">
            <div id="loading-container">
                <h1 id="loading_text">Loading...</h1>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <header>
      <a id="logo" href="user_profile.html">
        <h1 id="name">Name</h1>
        <h2 id="hello">Hello</h2>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="user_profile.html">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="user_info.html" class="selected">Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="user_specials.html">Specials</a></li>
          <li><a href="user_social.html">Social</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>      
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css

```
header {
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  padding:5px 0 0 0;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 102;

}

#logo {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
}

h1 {
  font-family:'Nunito', 'sans-serif';
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size:1.75em;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:0.8em;
}

h2 {
  margin:-5px 0 0;
  font-size:0.75em;
  font-weight:normal;
}

ul {
    padding: 0 0;
}

#loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 99;

}

#loading-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    z-index: 99;
}

#loading_image {

    display: block;
  margin: auto;
    z-index: 100;

} 

#loading_text {
    color: black;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 101;
  vertical-align: middle

}
```

As you can see I set the `z-index` of the header higher than everything else but it is still below the loading screen here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tovejedazi/edit?html,css,output) with a running example, in the example I show the loading screen for 3 seconds.

How can I get the header above the loading screen?

Thanks

Comment: Set positioning on the header. Use position fixed, absolute, or relative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`z-index` woks by `position`. Add `position:relative` to the `header`.

> **[Point, Note](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index#Point.2C_Note)**:
>
> Only works on positioned elements(`position: absolute;`, `position: relative;` or `position: fixed;`).

[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/yanuxon/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 4):

Use this on the header tag:

```
position: relative;
```

this one will also work but could change the rest of the html, I don't know what else you have on it.

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 3):

just add in the header{}

```
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
```

If I've got the question right this should do what you need.